# Button should change text every two presses

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a Tic Tac Toe game using Visual Basic. After pressing the button, the button should firstly turn to "O" then the next press should be a "X" however it seems that it continues placing "O".

```
    Dim turn As Boolean
    turn = True 'true = X turn, false = Y turn
    Dim b As Button

    b = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    If (turn) Then
        b.Text = "O"
    Else
        b.Text = "X"
        turn = Not turn <<< This seems to not to be working...

        b.Enabled = False
    End If
```

Comment: Where is turn declared? In the class or function?  Sounds like it should be a class/form variable so it won't be recreated every time a button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the `turn` variable outside the method, so that it is a member of the class and not a local variable that is recreated each time.

Also, you should flip the state after each change, not only when an X is placed, and the same for disabling the button.

Example:

```
Dim turn As Boolean = True 'true = X turn, false = Y turn

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

  If turn Then
    b.Text = "O"
  Else
    b.Text = "X"
  End If

  turn = Not turn
  b.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I see a trace of C# in there ;)

Comment: Or, if `turn` is not required outside the click handler, it could be declared inside it as a `Static` variable.

Comment: @the_lotus As Guffa appears to be otherwise occupied, I've removed the traces of C#. You could have done it too ;)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It was only in the method declaration that there was C# code though, the rest was actually from the original code. :)